# Should encryption algorithms like DES be applied on bits or bytes?

Tags: java, encryption, des

I've found some code samples on the internet which are encrypting bytes using CipherInputStream or something...What if I had a file containing like a 1000 bits, how can I apply DES on it?? I'm doing it in java

Comment: You know that bytes are simply groups of 8 bits, right?

Comment: Yes I know! I actually also have a byte array which has values like 7,-115,88....and so on

Comment: People are helping you, be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Java has no primitive type that allows you access to anything lesser than a byte. You'll therefore need to work on bytes, and not bits in Java.

> What if I had a file containing like a 1000 bits, how can I apply DES on it?

Use bytes. The [Cipher.doUpdate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update%28byte%5B%5D%29) and [Cipher.doFinal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28byte%5B%5D%29) methods use bytes, rather an array of them. Use a suitable padding scheme to account for any unpadded data.

Comment: ... and how many Bits represent a Byte is given by `java.lang.Byte.SIZE`.

Comment: Shame on me. What's the JLS? :-)

Comment: Java Language Specification. Here's the [obligatory link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2) to the section of the JLS that would interest you.

Comment: @Fatal, it had to be. Otherwise, compiler writers would have taken shortcuts leading to possibly unportable code. Also note that the JLS does not define boolean to be a 1-bit value. It only states that it is either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a reasonable question, despite the down-votes.

Many encryption modes (such as CBC) require that the input is a multiple of the block size of the underlying cipher (.e.g. 16 bytes for AES or 8 bytes for DES). To achieve this one uses a padding scheme.
Whether you can encrypt a plaintext with an arbitrary bit-length depends on what padding scheme you use.

The most commonly used padding scheme (i.e. PKCS #5 padding) prepends n bytes of value n to the plaintext.
This obviously requires that the plaintext is in bytes. But there are lesser known padding schemes that allow arbitrary inputs. For example, the so called "bit padding" appends a single 1 bit to your plaintext and the appends as many 0 bits as necessary until the length of your input is a multiple of the block size of your cipher. For example, the ISO/IEC 9797-1 standard is proposing this.

When deciding, whether you want to support arbitrary bit-lengths in your application you also have to consider the crypto libraries that you want to use. While some crypto algorithms have been standarized to allow inputs of arbitrary sizes in bits, it may not be implemented by your crypto library.
E.g. the hash function SHA-1 is well defined for inputs such as the 4-bit string '0101', but you
might have some trouble finding a library that can actually compute this hash.